# Insert Returning last ID with PDO

Tags: sql, postgresql, pdo

I am trying to get the last/current ID submitted in an Insert, I have tried `lastInsertId` however that didn't work. Alternatively I have used `returning` on the end of my insert. However that was using pg_sql. How would I use the returning line, with PDO? I am stuck with the logic of getting the value displayed using PDO in the second option.

php 5.1.6

See below

**Doesn't Work**

```
 $stmt ->execute();
 $newsheetID = $conn->lastInsertId('sheet_id');
 echo $newsheetID . "last id";
```

**Works But is pg_sql, I would like to get this working for PDO**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  username, additionalvolunteers) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]', '$username','$_POST[additionalvolunteers]') returning sheet_id";

echo $sql;
$result = pg_query($sql);
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
$sheet_id_post = $row[0];
echo $sheet_id_post . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question already? Spaming with the same question considered impolite behavior, you know.

Comment: No I changed the question, the first question yesterday was based on lastInsertid, this question is looking at using returning instead. I though as it is a different technique it was better to create a new question rather than edit the existing one as that would cause more confusion as it alters the scope.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, why don't you try to fetch the result using PDO regular methods?

Comment: An interesting coincidence. You have got answers from someone whose questions you are eagerly answer in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for this, if you cannot get lastInsertId to work, this will do the job, a couple of extra lines tho:

```
              foreach ($stmt as $row)
             {
              $sheet_id_post = $row[0];
              echo $sheet_id_post;
             }
```

You can always msg me. Or head to php website look for a similar loop and alter it, my answer is very similar to yours and when I first did this I just went to php.net :-)

Comment: Anyone to explain what foreach loop here for?